# Cannot create wifi hotspot

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, wifi-direct, madwifi, wifi-hardware-switch

I used connectify to create hotspot in windows. in ubuntu 12.04 i want to create an hotspot, i tried ap-hotspot to create hotspot but it is showing  Your wireless card does not support Access Point mode
how to create a hotspot .
wifi adapter PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether your card supports AP mode. To do this execute the following

```
sudo aptitude install iw
iw list
```

Look for `Supported interface modes:`

`AP` should be listed